# Is there any false case for that: $\exists x \in D, \forall y \in D, P(x, y) \implies P(y, x)$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Is there any false case for that: $\exists x \in D, \forall y \in D, P(x, y) \implies P(y, x)$?\

I just can get the true case.\

How can we define D and P in a false case?\

Thx guys.

Comment: What are $D$ and $P$?

Comment: could be defined by ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Rock, paper, scissors?  Let $P(x,y)=x$ beats $y$.  Rock beats scissors, but scissors doesn't beat rock.  Scissors beats paper but paper doesn't beat scissors.  Paper beats rock, but rock doesn't beat paper.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error in my example.

Answer (score 1):

$D = \varnothing$ seems like a pretty obvious (vacuous) falsification.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in the formula : $∃x∈D,∀y∈D,P(x,y) \rightarrow P(y,x)$ (call it : (A)) the *scope* of the quantifiers is the conditional, and not only the antecedent; i.e. :

> (A) --- $∃x∀y (P(x,y) \rightarrow P(y,x))$.

If so, assume as domain $D$ of the interpretation the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers* and interpret the *predicate* $P$ as the relation "less than" ($<$).

Consider the negation of the formula above, i.e. :

$\lnot ∃x∀y (P(x,y) \rightarrow P(y,x))$,

which is :

$∀x∃y \lnot (P(x,y) \rightarrow P(y,x))$.

By the equivalence of $A \rightarrow B$ with $\lnot A \lor B$ and *double negation*, this is equivalent to :

$∀x∃y (P(x,y) \land \lnot P(y,x))$.

We have that :

> $(n < n+1) \land \lnot (n+1 < n)$

is *true* for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

Thus :

> $\exists y ((n < y) \land \lnot (y < n))$

is *true* for every $n$, i.e.

> > $\forall x\exists y ((x < y) \land \lnot (y < x))$

is *true* in $\mathbb N$.

In conclusion, we have found an interpretation in which the *negation* of the formula (A) above is true; thus, in this interpretation, (A) is *false*.